# Unexpectedly nil hashing a password

Tags: swift, sha256

I'm trying to hash a password with SHA256 method:

```
class CryptoHandler {

    static func sha256(_ str: String) -> String? {
        let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let shaData = sha256(data!)
        let rc = String(data: shaData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String?
        return rc
    }

     static func sha256(_ data: Data) -> Data { var res = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)); data.withUnsafeBytes { _ = CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &res) }; return Data(bytes: res) }


    static func getHashedPassword (pwd: String) -> String{
        let hash = sha256(pwd)
        return hash!
    }
}
```

When I try to execute `getHashedPassword ("0123456789")` I have the following error in `return hash!` line:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Why this happens? How I can solve it?

Comment: How do you know shaData is data encoded as string? Only then shaData would be decodable with .utf8 to string. What you probably want is to represent your shaData as a String, but there are many ways to represent Data as a string. You can hex-encode it to String, you can base64 it, etc. Best force every optional up there and see where it crashes and look at your assumptions what doesn‘t work. Then make the sha256-function return a String instead, since if you can‘t rely on a hash function to always work, what is it worth?

Comment: `let rc = String(data: shaData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String?` Here is where I receive the nil value. So that conversion it's not working correctly.  @Purpose. I just need to get the string, then subtract the first 16 values and finally save it on the DB.

Comment: Tell me why do you think shaData, the underlying bits and bytes are a representation of a .utf8-String? What if it is just random data, how could that function possibly return not nil? Then you can look up how to encode Data to a hex-representation. Or a base64-whatever you want the String-representation to look like.

Comment: I have change that line for `let rc = shaData.base64EncodedString(options: [])` and now I don't receive a nil value. I receive a Base64Enconded String. But, still need to  be decoded.

Comment: You mean you want to go back from the base64-representation to the Data-representation? For that you can use [the way back](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1410081-init).

Comment: No to data, to String.

Comment: `No to data, to String`: What do you mean? You got your base64-encoded Data as a String as far as I can tell in rc. `let shaData = Data(base64Encoded: rc)` should let you go back to the Data-presentation of your sha. If you are sure the String content IS base64-encoded Data you can even force it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash occurs because you cannot create a `String` from encrypted `Data`. You have to use `base64` or `hex` representation.

This code creates a `hex` encoded string and doesn't use optionals at all.

```
class CryptoHandler {

    static func sha256(_ str: String) -> String {
        let data = Data(str.utf8)
        let shaData = sha256(data)
        return shaData.hexString
    }

    static func sha256(_ data: Data) -> Data {
        var res = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH));
        data.withUnsafeBytes { _ = CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &res) };
        return Data(bytes: res)
    }

    static func getHashedPassword (pwd: String) -> String{
        let hash = sha256(pwd)
        return hash
    }
}

extension Data {
    var hexString : String {
        return self.map{ String(format:"%02x", $0) }.joined()
    }
}

CryptoHandler.getHashedPassword(pwd:"0123456789")
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be encoded. What I need it just to create the sha256 of one string. The same as this page do. [link](https://passwordsgenerator.net/sha256-hash-generator/)

Comment: It **does** have to be encoded. On the linked site the data is hex string encoded. I added the code as `Data` extension

Comment: Perfect. That was what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
let rc = String(data: shaData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String?
```

will return nil value and you are forcing to compiler a value using `return hash!` Exclamation mark at the end of `hash` constant in `getHashedPassword` method.

You can fix it by modifying `getHashedPassword` method by accepting an optional value

ex:

```
static func getHashedPassword (pwd: String) -> String? 
{
   let hash = sha256(pwd)
   return hash 
}
```

Comment: And how can I fix it?

Comment: provide an optional return type in getHashedPassword method.
ex: 
static func getHashedPassword (pwd: String) -> String? {
        let hash = sha256(pwd)
        return hash
    }

Comment: I think you are not probably using hashing functions for the password.